# .profile or .bash_profile

Tags: ubuntu, mac, environment-variables

I'm confused, where do I set environmental variables?

In .profile or in .bash_profile?

I am using both mac osx and ubuntu.

Confused as to which one I use here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

read http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files:

```
 When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a 
 non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads 
 and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file
 exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, 
 ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes
 commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The 
 --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit
 this behavior.
```

other shells load `~/.profile` as well (zsh, tcsh) .. so, i would put environment stuff into `~/.profile`.

**mac osx related update (thanks  @Matt B)**:

for gui programs read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1067.html and edit `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` carefully.

Comment: In addition, ~/.profile is read before your window manager starts, so environment variables that you want to be seen by your window manager or the applications it launches should be put in your ~/.profile.

Comment: @garyjohn: Is that the case for Ubuntu or Mac OS?

Comment: @zneak: I'm reasonably sure about Ubuntu, less so about Mac OS X, but I don't have access to either one to verify at the moment.

Comment: @zneak: @garyjohn's remark does not apply to Mac OS X.  To change environment variables for GUI programs, you must place your settings into `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.  See more information here: http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AquaEnvVar.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you use bash, in `~/.bash_profile`. If you use other shells, in `~/.profile`