# OS X Mountain Lion terminal tab name + open a new tab in the same directory

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

1) In Mountain Lion, through Preferences, you can change the setting of Terminal so that a new tab can be opened in the same directory as the opening tab. (i.e. if I am at ~/workspace and I open a new tab, then the new tab will be at ~/workspace).

2) Also in Mountain Lion, it is possible to have the title of the tab automatically reflect the current directory's basename via the following directive in ~/.profile:

```
# automatically change the title of the terminal window to the directory basename
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n -e "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"'
```

However, this also seems to remove terminal's ability to open a new tab in the same directory as the opening tab. That is, having 2) seems to make 1) ineffective. Is there a way to fix this issue so both of these things can happen at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default `PROMPT_COMMAND` behavior is defined in [`/etc/bashrc`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-86.1/bashrc) and adds the path to the working directory to the *window title* in a way that preserves the *Same Working Directory* functionality (as `file://` URL), and even allows browsing to ancestor directories by <kbd>Command</kbd>-clicking the title bar.

If you additionally want to set the *tab title* to the base name of the working directory, you need to preserve the original `PROMPT_COMMAND`. In your user profile's shell initialization file of choice, use the following:

```
function set_tab_title {
  echo -n -e "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="set_tab_title ; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks so much. By the way, could you be so kind as to educate me a little bit about the difference between bashrc and profile, and /etc/bashrc vs ~/.bashrc. When are each loaded when an Apple Terminal starts up? Thank you again very much!

Comment: @platypus [How those files are used by bash](http://superuser.com/questions/171035/profile-or-bash-profile). Additionally, note that on OS X's Terminal.app, every shell is an interactive login shell, whereas on Linux it's usually just interactive (non-login) shells. `~/.profile` might be used by other shell programs.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like ~/.profile is the last file to be loaded so it's safe to put all the custom configurations like PROMPT_COMMAND in it to be loaded by the terminal. Earlier you were saying PROMPT_COMMAND should be in ~/.bashrc FWIW, could you explain that a little?

Comment: @platypus Read that again. It only gets loaded if none of the other exist. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is something you want for all interactive shells. So it should probably be loaded if you run `bash --login` (when opening a new tab) as well as just `bash`. The file for that is `~/.bashrc`. If you create `~/.bash_profile` as well, that needs to `source ~/.bashrc`, otherwise it doesn't get loaded.

Comment: I recommend replacing `echo -n -e` with `printf` in this instance, to avoid interpreting the contents of the directory name by separating the escape sequence from its content (this also means you can use the mnemonic `\e` and `\a` instead of octal for the control characters): `printf '\e]0;%s\a' "${PWD##*/}"`